# Pointing out to index.html file on server

Tags: xml, phonegap-build

How do I indicate in my `config.xml` file to start my phone app from the `index.html` on my web server? This is the default code given to me:

```
<access origin="https://127.0.0.1*"/>
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
<access origin="https://server_add/folder/index.html*"/>
```

I'm using PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what that does. The access tag just allows access to external resources.

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://server_add" />
```

Once you do this, you can easily point you index file to where it needs to go.

```
<body onload="document.location.href='http://server_add/index.html';">
```

Comment: so then this means i can just create and index.html file and place this code in the body and i'm ready to compile?